# Why does the Euler transform produce a universal lock?

Tags: graphics

Why does a universal lock occur when a transformation is split into three basis (x,y,z) axes using euler transformation?

Comment: because euler rotations affects each other creating singularities and edge cases when used as continuous angles instead of bounding them to their usable ranges ... threre are ways of remedy the discontinuities on edge cases but its a lot of conditions while using [coumulative 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) have no restrictions like that... btw most games ignoring that while using euler angles creating the well know bugs like you cant rotate beond certain angles, view or model spins uncontrolably, or it flips upside down without any reason etc.

Comment: btw IIRC the "universal lock" is called **Gimbal lock** in English